# How to add commas in number in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add commas in numbers in JavaScript ?
For example I want to add commas in this number 1445456523.56594

Answer (score 10):

Use `toLocaleString`

```js
var n=1445456523.56594;
console.log(n.toLocaleString());
```